# Как в конструктор класса добавить возможность выбора потока для вывода информации (cout или cerr)?

Tags: c++, конструктор, деструктор, класс

Имеется класс `LogDuration` в заголовочном файле, которым я высчитываю время работы функции и вывожу информацию в поток cout. Вызов идёт с одним аргументом типа string : `LogDuration(someFunc);`.

Я хочу расширить класс, чтобы по дефолту информация выводилась в поток cerr, а при вызове со вторым аргументом типа ostream в cout: `LogDuration(someFunc, cout);`.
Сделать это я хочу через конструктор, но он всячески ругается при попытке присвоения переменной типа ostream какого - либо значения ошибкой

> на функцию нельзя ссылаться так как эта функция удалена

Вот код:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

class LogDuration {
public:

    using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;

    LogDuration() = default;

    LogDuration(const std::string& id, ostream& out)
        : id_(id), out_(out) {  //В этой строке сразу после out_ выдаёт ошибку, указанную выше
    }
   
    ~LogDuration() {

        using namespace std::chrono;
        using namespace std::literals;

        const auto end_time = Clock::now();
        const auto dur = end_time - start_time_;
        out_ << id_ << ": "s << duration_cast<milliseconds>(dur).count() << " ms"s << std::endl;
    }

private:
    const std::string id_;
    const Clock::time_point start_time_ = Clock::now();
    std::ostream out_;
};

Не знаю, что делать. Поиск в гугле ничего не дал.
```

Comment: В классе тоже хранить ссылку: `std::ostream &out_;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Весь ответ - в одной строчке:

```
std::ostream& out_;
```

Ну и раз

> по дефолту информация выводилась в поток cerr

то

```
LogDuration(const std::string& id, ostream& out = cerr)
```

и

```
std::ostream& out_ = cerr;
```

Comment: Всё помогло! А почему ссылка необходима в данном случае? 
std::ostream& out_;

Comment: Потому что **потоки не копируются**. Если ответ устроил — закрывайте вопрос, приняв ответ с помощью "птички" слева от него...